# How do I stylize a Text Shape in JavaFX using a CSS style sheet without assigning it a style-class?

Tags: java, css, javafx-8, fxml

I have a fairly simple JavaFX control that I am trying to stylize with a CSS stylesheet.
I have the background set up fine but I have several Text shapes that are necessary because the control itself can vary in size and I want to scale the text with the control.

I am trying to stylize the text in a CSS with `.text{/*CSS Code*/}` but it's not working:

```
.text{
   -fx-fill: #818181;
   -fx-effect: innershadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.7) , 6, 0.0 , 0 , 2 );   
}
```

When I open the FXML file in Scene Builder I have to apply it a style-class before I see the effect.

I wouldn't care but I also want to apply effects when hovering or clicking on the text shapes and evidently with a style class accessing the pseudo-class :hover doesn't work, and by extension I will presume no other pseudo-class works either:

```
.text:hover{
    -fx-fill: #818181; 
}
```

This is the rest I have:

```
root {
    display: block
}

.root{
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
        from 0% 0% to 100% 100%, #b478ff 0%, #9400d3 100%
    );
}
```

I set the root layout (a gridpane) style-class to "root" and that works (i can see the background gradient colors just fine).

I love the idea of CSS but I can never ever seem to get it to work and it drives me nuts. What am I doing wrong here? To text shapes not have accessible CSS pesudo-classes? Or even classes at all? What am I missing from this?

Answer (score 0):

You have set -fx-fill to the same color in text and text:hover.

For me it works, when I use your CSS: the text of a label and button show a hover effect (I changed fx-fill to another value in text:hover).

Example code: http://pastebin.com/GNDwz626

Answer (score 0):

#### ... I have to apply it a style-class before I see the effect.

you have to do that sometimes unless you use the special css classes

---

#### I love the idea of CSS ... To text shapes not have accessible CSS pesudo-classes? ...?

what you need to do is **read the modena.css**
which is in the **jfxrt.jar (location jre\lib\ext)** search for it in your **jre** path modena.css is located at[image: location]

---

### from modena.css

here's some information extracted from the css.

```
/*******************************************************
 *                                                     *
 * Text COMMON                                         *
 *                                                     *
 ******************************************************/

.text-input {
    /* ... */
}
.text-input:focused {
    /* ... */
}

/*******************************************************
 *                                                     *
 * TextArea                                            *
 *                                                     *
 ******************************************************/

.text-area {
    /* ... */
}
.text-area > .scroll-pane {
    /* ... */
}
.text-area > .scroll-pane > .scroll-bar:horizontal {
    /* ... */
}
.text-area > .scroll-pane > .scroll-bar:vertical {
    -/* ... */
}
.text-area > .scroll-pane > .corner {
    /* ... */
}
.text-area .content {
    /* ... */
}
.text-area:focused .content {
    /* ... */
}
```

### ScenicView

There is a software called scenic view,  you can get it from the fx experience website. You may also use that software to find information about control's css classes.

Comment: That's for text-input and text-area though. I am looking to stylize this here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/Text.html

Comment: You can find more information by reading the css. This way you can do further research yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Text is a shape. So its slightly different.

// Put this in your css

```
/* This sets the fill for the Text Shape */
Text {
    -fx-fill: white;
}
```